# check EmptyOrNull for unknown amount of collections and maps

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8

I am trying to achieve an `util` as this in Spring Boot:

```
public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Collection... collectionList) {
    for (Collection collection : collectionList) {
        if (!Collections.isEmpty(collection)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

so I can handle cases as:

- isAllEmptyOrNull(listOfCat);
- isAllEmptyOrNull(listOfDog, mapOfStringToString);
- isAllEmptyOrNull(listOfDog, listOfCat);
- isAllEmptyOrNull(listOfDog, listOfCat, mapOfStringToList, mapOfStringToMap);

Any help will be sincerely appreciated :)

#### Updated 2018-12-06

Thanks for the help of @Deadpool, my solution turns out:

```
public static boolean isAllCollectionEmptyOrNull(Collection... collections) {
    for (Collection collection : collections) {
        if (!Collections.isEmpty(collection)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isAllMapEmptyOrNull(Map... maps) {
    for (Map map : maps) {
        if (!Collections.isEmpty(map)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Of course, you can use `stream` and `method overloading` as [nullpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644376/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-emptyornull-for-unknown-amount-of-collections/53644456?noredirect=1#answer-53644517) does.

Comment: If as you mention util is already there, what are you trying to achieve then?

Comment: You can also live only with the method that accepts collections and, when you have a map, pass `myMap.keySet()` or `myOtherMap.values()` to it. Alternatively, you could receive `Object...` and use `instanceof Collection` and `instanceof Map` for each object in the varargs array, and delegate to either one of the two methods you've posted as a solution. The downside would be that you could pass anything to this method, i.e. apart from maps and collections, you could also pass strings, numbers, etc. And you should deal with those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. You cannot create it as generic as you are looking for since a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) is not a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html).

And of course `Collection... collectionList` signifies var args for `Collection` type.

The only way would be to break them into two separate stubs as :

```
public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Collection... collectionList) {
    return Arrays.stream(collectionList).allMatch(Collection::isEmpty);
}

public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Map... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps).allMatch(Map::isEmpty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have two different util methods one for to check `Collection` objects and another one for `Map` objects, since `Map` is not child of `Collection` interface

```
public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Collection... collectionList) {
    return Arrays.stream(collectionList).anyMatch(item->item==null || item.isEmpty());
}

public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Map... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps).anyMatch(item->item==null || item.isEmpty());
}
```

To check all objects `null` or `empty`

```
public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Collection... collectionList) {
    return Arrays.stream(collectionList).allMatch(item->item==null || item.isEmpty());
}

public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Map... maps) {
    return Arrays.stream(maps).allMatch(item->item==null || item.isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: I just found it out too...thanks it's the **reason** but I also wonder is there any **cleaner** way to walk around it?

Comment: cleaner way? can you describe it? i believe it is clear @Hearen

Comment: Using a `single` method...it seems it's impossible

Comment: In this case it is impossible, because you can't overload same method with different stream objects and also you can't use generics here @Hearen

Comment: why use `anyMatch` for a signature reading **all** null or empty? [why not `allMatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644517/17461180)

Comment: i mean it's just example, i will update with both @nullpointer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public static boolean isAllEmptyOrNull(Collection... collectionList) {
    return Arrays.stream(collectionList).anyMatch(Collection::isEmpty);
}
```

Comment: the issue is not about `stream`, it's about the `parameters` declaration.

Comment: this wouldn't handle `Map` still